# How to POST an authenticated Jenkins job using Java

Tags: java, rest, jenkins

All:

I need to be able to POST a job to Jenkins using the Jenkins REST API but have not been able to get past authentication. I have been attempting to do this for a few days now and have researched answers on both this site and on the Jenkins site. I have been trying to use the Apache HttpClient with no success (even with preemptive validation). I keep getting error code 403 - forbidden. Has anyone been able to do this successfully? Here is the code that I am working with:

```
package stackoverflow.question;

import gsafame.sample;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpHost;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.auth.AuthScope;
import org.apache.http.auth.UsernamePasswordCredentials;
import org.apache.http.client.AuthCache;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.CredentialsProvider;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.CloseableHttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.client.protocol.HttpClientContext;
import org.apache.http.impl.auth.BasicScheme;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicAuthCache;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicCredentialsProvider;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClients;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;

public class PreEmptiveAuth {
final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(sample.class.getCanonicalName());
private JobData jd;
private CredentialsProvider credpro;
private AuthScope as;
private UsernamePasswordCredentials upc;
private String url;

public PreEmptiveAuth(JobData jd) {
    this.jd = jd;
    credpro = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
    as = new AuthScope(jd.getServer(), 443);
    upc = new UsernamePasswordCredentials(jd.getUsername(), jd.getPassword());
    credpro.setCredentials(as, upc);
    url = String.format("%s:8080/jenkins/job/%s/buildWithParameters", jd.getServer(), jd.getJob());
}

public void runTagJob() throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {
    log.entering(this.getClass().getCanonicalName(), "runTagJob");
    log.info("Entering runTagJob");
    CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.custom()
            .setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credpro).build();
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
    List <NameValuePair> nvps = new ArrayList <NameValuePair>();
    nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", jd.getUsername()));
    nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", jd.getPassword()));
    nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("apiToken", jd.getToken()));
    httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nvps));
    CloseableHttpResponse response2 = httpclient.execute(httpPost);

    try {
        System.out.println(response2.getStatusLine());
        HttpEntity entity2 = response2.getEntity();
        // do something useful with the response body
        // and ensure it is fully consumed
        EntityUtils.consume(entity2);
    } finally {
        response2.close();
    }
    log.info("Exiting runTagJob");
    log.exiting(this.getClass().getCanonicalName(), "runTagJob");
}

public void runPreTagJob() throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {
    log.entering(this.getClass().getCanonicalName(), "runPreTagJob");
    log.info("Entering runPreTagJob");
    HttpHost targetHost = new HttpHost(jd.getServer(), 8080, "http");
    CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.custom()
            .setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credpro).build();
    try {

        // Create AuthCache instance
        AuthCache authCache = new BasicAuthCache();
        // Generate BASIC scheme object and add it to the local auth cache
        BasicScheme basicAuth = new BasicScheme();
        authCache.put(targetHost, basicAuth);

        // Add AuthCache to the execution context
        HttpClientContext localContext = HttpClientContext.create();
        localContext.setAuthCache(authCache);

        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
        List <NameValuePair> nvps = new ArrayList <NameValuePair>();
        nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", jd.getUsername()));
        nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", jd.getPassword()));
        nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("apiToken", jd.getToken()));
        httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nvps));
        CloseableHttpResponse response2 = httpclient.execute(targetHost, httpPost, localContext);

        try {
            System.out.println(response2.getStatusLine());
            HttpEntity entity2 = response2.getEntity();
            // do something useful with the response body
            // and ensure it is fully consumed
            EntityUtils.consume(entity2);
        } finally {
            response2.close();
        }    
    } finally {
        httpclient.close();
    }
    log.info("Exiting runPreTagJob");
    log.exiting(this.getClass().getCanonicalName(), "runPreTagJob");
}

}
```

The JobData object that gets passed into this class contains information like username, password, server, and job information. I hope this helps!

Comment: Please post the code you're using.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After researching on several sites, I managed to piece enough information together to come up with a solution. I am using older HTTP authentication code that is in some instances deprecated - but it works when nothing else would. If anyone has a better solution, I would be interested in seeing it. Anyway, here it is:

Main Class:

```
package stackoverflow.answer;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;

public class sample {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(sample.class.getCanonicalName());
        JobData jd = new JobData();

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        try {
            System.out.print("What is your user name? ");
            jd.setUsername(input.next());
            System.out.print("What is your password? ");
            jd.setPassword(input.next());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.log(Level.SEVERE, "The system encountered an exception while attempting to login");
        } finally {
              input.close();
        }

        jd.setJob("TestREST");
        jd.setServer("http://YOUR-SERVER");
        jd.setPort("YOUR-PORT");
        // set the parameters
        List<NameValuePair> parameters = jd.getParameters();
        parameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("SONAR-TARGET", "true"));
        parameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("RELEASE", "1311.1.1"));
        parameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("REVISION", "HEAD"));
        // run the job
        JenkinsPoster jp = new JenkinsPoster(jd);
        log.info("executing postJenkinsJob");
        jp.postJenkinsJob();
        log.info("executed postJenkinsJob");
    }   
}
```

The JobData class (holds information about the job you need to run)

```
package stackoverflow.answer;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;

public class JobData {
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String token;
    private String server;
    private String port;
    private String job;
    private List<NameValuePair> parameters;

    public JobData() {
        parameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    }

    public String getUsername() {return username;}
    public void setUsername(String username) {this.username = username;}
    public String getPassword() {return password;}
    public void setPassword(String password) {this.password = password;}
    public String getToken() {return token;}
    public void setToken(String token) {this.token = token;}
    public String getServer() {return server;}
    public void setServer(String server) {this.server = server;}
    public String getPort() {return port;}
    public void setPort(String port) {this.port = port;}
    public String getJob() {return job;}
    public void setJob(String job) {this.job = job;}
    public List<NameValuePair> getParameters() {return parameters;}
}
```

The JenkinsPoster class (contains the business logic to connect to Jenkins and POST the job)

```
package stackoverflow.answer;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.auth.AuthScope;
import org.apache.http.auth.UsernamePasswordCredentials;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.auth.BasicScheme;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.protocol.BasicHttpContext;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;

public class JenkinsPoster {
    final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(getClass().getCanonicalName());
    private JobData jd;

    public JenkinsPoster(JobData jobData) {
        this.jd = jobData;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public void postJenkinsJob() throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        log.entering(getClass().getCanonicalName(), "JenkinsPoster");
        // Jenkins url
        String jenkinsUrl = String.format("%s:%s/jenkins", jd.getServer(), jd.getPort());
        log.info("url = " + jenkinsUrl);
        // Create your httpclient
        DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        // Then provide the right credentials
        client.getCredentialsProvider().setCredentials(new AuthScope(AuthScope.ANY_HOST, AuthScope.ANY_PORT),
        new UsernamePasswordCredentials(jd.getUsername(), jd.getPassword()));
        // Generate BASIC scheme object and stick it to the execution context
        BasicScheme basicAuth = new BasicScheme();
        BasicHttpContext context = new BasicHttpContext();
        context.setAttribute("preemptive-auth", basicAuth);
        // Add as the first (because of the zero) request interceptor
        // It will first intercept the request and preemptively initialize the authentication scheme if there is not
        client.addRequestInterceptor(new PreemptiveAuth(), 0);

        // Post the request to start the build
        List<NameValuePair> parameters = jd.getParameters();
        UrlEncodedFormEntity uefe = null;
        String buildUrl = "";
        if (parameters.isEmpty()) {
            buildUrl = jenkinsUrl + "/job/" + jd.getJob() + "/build";
        }
        else {
            buildUrl = jenkinsUrl + "/job/" + jd.getJob() + "/buildWithParameters";
            uefe = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(parameters);
        }
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost(buildUrl);
        post.setHeader("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0");
        if (uefe != null) {
            post.setEntity(uefe);
        }

        try {
            // Execute your request with the given context
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(post, context);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            log.info(EntityUtils.toString(entity));
            EntityUtils.consume(entity);
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally {
            client.close();
        }
        log.exiting(getClass().getCanonicalName(), "JenkinsPoster");
    }
}
```

... and finally, the PreemptiveAuth class that the previous class uses to preemptively login to Jenkins.

```
package stackoverflow.answer;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.http.HttpException;
import org.apache.http.HttpHost;
import org.apache.http.HttpRequest;
import org.apache.http.HttpRequestInterceptor;
import org.apache.http.auth.AuthScheme;
import org.apache.http.auth.AuthScope;
import org.apache.http.auth.AuthState;
import org.apache.http.auth.Credentials;
import org.apache.http.client.CredentialsProvider;
import org.apache.http.client.protocol.ClientContext;
import org.apache.http.protocol.ExecutionContext;
import org.apache.http.protocol.HttpContext;

public class PreemptiveAuth implements HttpRequestInterceptor {

    public void process(HttpRequest request, HttpContext context)
            throws HttpException, IOException {
        // Get the AuthState
        AuthState authState = (AuthState) context.getAttribute(ClientContext.TARGET_AUTH_STATE);

        // If no auth scheme available yet, try to initialize it preemptively
        if (authState.getAuthScheme() == null) {
            AuthScheme authScheme = (AuthScheme) context.getAttribute("preemptive-auth");
            CredentialsProvider credsProvider = (CredentialsProvider) context
                    .getAttribute(ClientContext.CREDS_PROVIDER);
            HttpHost targetHost = (HttpHost) context.getAttribute(ExecutionContext.HTTP_TARGET_HOST);
            if (authScheme != null) {
                Credentials creds = credsProvider.getCredentials(new AuthScope(targetHost.getHostName(), targetHost
                        .getPort()));
                if (creds == null) {
                    throw new HttpException("No credentials for preemptive authentication");
                }
                authState.setAuthScheme(authScheme);
                authState.setCredentials(creds);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Documentation on handling Jenkins' REST API authentication can be found here:

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Authenticating+scripted+clients

Comment: Thanks for answering but the link you shared was probably the first one I investigated. Using their example code, I get to a page that tells me that I must "POST" my request. We are using Jenkins version 1.502 by the way and so if you have something that works it could be an issue with the version that we are using. Do you have a working example that you can share?

Comment: OK - I'll take a look. Wasn't sure if you'd seen that doc or not.

Comment: Have you tried connecting with wget on the command line to see if it's accepting your request?

Comment: No, I have not tried wget and will not be able to since in my environment I do not have admin rights to install software. I don't even have curl.

Comment: I am using a laptop running Windows 7.

Comment: See if you can get the equivalent working with powershell maybe? Or use [POSTMAN](http://www.getpostman.com/) even to test the authentication flow outside of your code.